# What is wrong with Facebook and Twitter APIs?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, twitter

Is anyone else noticing that facebook and twitters APIs aren't working?

For facebook even if I allow my application to have access to my wall

```
$facebook->getUser()
```

Is always 0... When I try to open **getLoginUrl** it just open pop-up and redirect it instantly to success return link...

Here is code:

```
require_once 'src/base_facebook.php';
require_once 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'oauth' => true,
  'cookie' => true
));

$req_perms = "publish_stream";

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user)
    {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'popup', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://xxxx.com/return_close.php?success=1', 'cancel_url' => 'http://xxxx.com/return_close.php?success=0','req_perms' => $req_perms, 'scope' => $req_perms));
    }
```

And for twitter it's like someone mistyped return link...
When I open **getAuthorizeURL** and when I log in it redirects me to this URL:

```
https://twitter.comoauth_callback/?oauth_token=yA2xjLsVRm9tIuVEysXnCV8R7TISW8tF94uznn7zlw&oauth_verifier=Io1N2I8zOEzJeBWI77WXFMqmMRNDfCrXZGQxXmxJLbI
```

Yes, **https://twitter.comoauth_callback/** is right, there is no / after .com, it's together, so I get not found page...

It's like both APIs have serious problems... Facebook sometimes work and sometimes doesn't, it's buggy a lot...

Facebook library downloaded from OFFICIAL GitHub page. Tried versions:

```
v3.1.1
v3.1.0
v3.0.1
```

And none of those work...

---

Update

Return URL ( redirect_uri ) **MUST** have facebook class included in file...

There is so many examples/documentations and none of those had this explained...

So, Facebook fixed... Twitter still not working...

---

Comment: You must be new to FB development. Don't worry, as soon as you figure it out, they'll change it. "If it ain't broke, fix it ' til it is."

Comment: "as soon as you figure it out, they'll change it" ? You mean this is happening all the time?

Comment: Oh, and enjoy the documentation.

Comment: So... Is this happening all the time or is it my fault?

Comment: No clue, I don't speak PHP. I'm not having any problems with the FB APIs today, so it's likely a bug in your PHP library or your code. But FB is intensity frustrating even at the best of times.

Comment: "Is anyone else noticing that facebook and twitters APIs aren't working?" --- wondered why do you think that their APIs are broken simultaneously but not your code is just written wrong?

Comment: Because I found tons of posts submitting getUser bug, and how can I change redirect link for twitter after login? It's on theirs side... So... How can it be me? And for facebook, how come it works sometime and sometime it doesn't... If it's my fault it won't work all the time, not sometimes does, and sometimes doesn't while I didn't change a thing... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, nothing is broken in the API. Where did you get the above code? and if you come up with it then based on what resource?

First of all, take a look at the [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) of the **OFFICIAL** PHP-SDK, you'll notice the following:

1. Only the [`facebook.php`](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php) file has been included, why not `base_facebook.php`? well because it's included in the `facebook.php` file!
2. Developers used to use `req_perms` but now to request permissions you just need to use `scope`
3. Take a look inside [`base_facebook.php`](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L203) for the params the `Facebook()` class expect: `appId`, `secret` and `fileUpload` **ONLY**
4. Only use the `display` parameter if you know what you are doing!
5. Use proper indentation with your code, it makes your life (and others!) much easier!

This been said, this is a rewrite of your code:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret
));

$req_perms = "publish_stream";

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'popup', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://xxxx.com/return_close.php?success=1', 'cancel_url' => 'http://xxxx.com/return_close.php?success=0', 'scope' => $req_perms));
}
```

Comment: Resources are downloaded from that OFFICIAL page, at top you have Downloads, and select v3.1.1... ;)
And I used that code you just send me, but it didn't worked, so I tried with those "fixes" changes... that's why it has this base_facebook, cookie/oauth parameters, and both scope and req_perms, ofc I try to find solution before I came here... ;) 5. I will used it properly if it was working okay...
Anyhow, your code doesn't work...

Comment: Obviously the code above is just to get you started it won't redirect you or do anything!. Also "didn't" work doesn't help us help you. What didn't work?

Comment: I changed my code the way you did, went to my Facebook, delete permissions for this App in my profile, then open page, and $user was 0. Then I open in pop-up $loginUrl, it showed me "Allow" question, I clicked on Allow, and it transferred me to success page. I reload my page, where this code is, and it still had $user 0... I tried 3 different browsers, tried cleaning my cookies/cache... And it still doesn't work... Also, I tried it on 3 latest versions, v3.1.1, v3.1.0 and v3.0.1 and none of those was working...

Comment: How about using the same exact example code at first just to check? and do not use older versions of the SDK.

Comment: Like I told you, I already did... Now, when you send me, and first time, when I started making it... All the same exact code... And it's not working... I am using latest version, but I put those too to check, but it's same, not working, so I am back to latest... It's strange that it was working sometimes and sometimes didn't, but now it's not working at all, and I didn't change a thing in meantime...

Comment: well, if you tried the same exact code like the example page and it didn't work then you either have some server issues (e.g.:cURL not installed) or your app settings are wrong

Comment: Curl is installed... And if my app settings are wrong, how it was working before? Also, what is **state** in return url? It have long code, is that used for something?

Comment: Tested on 3 different applications, and none is working... and all of them are returning success on pop-up open...